# Finding the Generators of the Adjoint Representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

*Qu: How (formally) - can I extract the generators in the adjoint representation from any given Lie algebra?*

*Attempt at Solution:*

Take a matrix lie group $G$, with lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. For me, this means:

$$ \mathfrak{g} = \bigg\{ X \, : \, exp(tX) \in G \; \forall t \in \mathbb{R}  \bigg\} $$

Then for every element $A\in G$ we can define a linear map. $Ad_{A}: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}, Ad_{A}(X):= AXA^{-1}$.(and you can show from an immeadiate substitution into the exponential that $AXA^{-1}$ will always be in $\mathfrak{g}$).

Can think of the *set* of these maps as a map - from the Lie group $G$ to the set of invertible linear maps on $\mathfrak{g}$  $Ad: G \rightarrow GL(\mathfrak{g})$

1. Easily checked that $GL(\mathfrak{g})$ is a valid group, and $Ad$ is then a group homomorphism
   (i.e $Ad$ is a group representation of $G$ over $\mathfrak{g}$)
2. $Ad$ is also a lie group homomorphism because it's continuous.

There's then a theorem [see e.g Hall, Introduction to Lie Algebras] that for every Lie group homomorphism, there's a corresponding homomorphism of the respective lie algebras i.e if $\Phi$ is a LG homomorphism $\Phi: G \rightarrow F$, then $!\exists$ $\phi: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{f}$

So if:

$$ Ad: G \rightarrow GL(\mathfrak{g}) $$ 
Then: 
$$ ad: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow gl(\mathfrak{g})$$

Where $gl(\mathfrak{g})$ is the Lie algebra of the group of invertible maps on $\mathfrak{g}$, $GL(\mathfrak{g})$

What I really want however, is to figure out what the generators are for this lie algebra. (So if for sake of argument we take $G=SL(2,\mathbb{R})$), given that I understand this - how do I go about getting to the generators?? i.e What are the generators in the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$?

I realise there are quick and dirty ways of doing this, but I'm confused as to how to do so formally.

Thanks!

Comment: If you say "generators" of  Lie algebra, do you mean basis? A Lie algebra is a vector space with a Lie bracket. Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507660/adjoint-representation-standard-basis-mathfraksl2-and-killing-form?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Sure :) I thought the set of generators was technically the any set of elements of the LA such that the smallest subalgebra which contained them *was* the LA... but that seems like the same thing as a basis set to me..

Comment: So then you know how to come from $G=SL(2,R)$ to the "generators" of the Lie algebra - a basis for the trace zero matrices of size $2$. The vector space has dimension $3$, therefore you get the three "generators" from the link.

Comment: By result that $det(exp(tX)) = exp(tTr(X))$ then the lie alebgra of $SL(2,R)$ is the set of $2\times 2$ traceless matrices.  $$ \mathfrak{sl}(2,R) = \bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \delta & -\alpha \end{pmatrix} \alpha,\beta,\delta\ \in \mathbb{R} \bigg\} $$ and it's then obvious how to get the basis matrices out of that - but I really don't understand how those adjoint matrices have been calculated. I think it's something obvious, but it's not clear to me, sorry.

Comment: It's just linear algebra. The images of the linear map $f$ of the basis are the column vectors of the matrix. So if $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ is a basis, then $0=[e_1,e_1]={\rm ad}(e_1)(e_1)$, so that the first column vector of the matrix ${\rm ad}(e_1)$ is $(0,0,0)^T$.